# How to checkout the source code from Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I need to download the source code from the Mercurial.

```
$ hg clone xmppframework.googlecode.com/hg xmppframework 
  warning: xmppframework.googlecode.com certificate with fingerprint b1:af:83:76:f3:81:b0:57:70:d8:07:42:c8:c1:b3:67:38:c8:7a:bc not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting) 
  requesting all changes 
  adding changesets 
  adding manifests 
  adding file changes
```

I tried it in terminal by using this link to download the source code.But the command is failed.

Anyone can help me to get rid of this.

Thanks to all,
Madan.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is, that you didn't added the fingerprint of google to your hgrc file.
There are two ways to solve the problem:

1. Use `http` instead of `https`, the disadvantage would be, that your traffic isn't encrypted anymore.

   > hg clone http://xmppframework.googlecode.com/hg/ xmppframework
2. Or add the fingerprint to you hgrc file:
   Please note that Google Code is changing the fingerprint sometimes. When the fingerprint below doesn't work, you can use this command (taken from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164804/get-certificate-fingerprint-of-https-server-from-command-line)) to detect the current fingerprint:

   > $ openssl s_client -connect xmppframework.googlecode.com:443 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout -in /dev/stdin

   > [hostfingerprints]
   >
   > xmppframework.googlecode.com = b1:af:83:76:f3:81:b0:57:70:d8:07:42:c8:c1:b3:67:38:c8:7a:bc

*Edited because original answer was ugly.*

Comment: Last login: Mon Feb 21 19:41:58 on ttys001 kishore-babu-bs-mac-mini:~ kishorebabub$ cd desktop kishore-babu-bs-mac-mini:desktop kishorebabub$ cd Monish_new kishore-babu-bs-mac-mini:Monish_new kishorebabub$ hg clone xmppframework.googlecode.com/hg xmppframework warning: xmppframework.googlecode.com certificate with fingerprint b1:af:83:76:f3:81:b0:57:70:d8:07:42:c8:c1:b3:67:38:c8:7a:bc not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting) requesting all changes adding changesets adding manifests adding file changes

Comment: Can you tell me which version of Mercurial you use ?, you can print that with $ hg --version

Comment: Please edit your question and post that output as a formatted block of text, makes it easier to read and easier to find.

Comment: It looks like it actually manages to clone the repository from that output though. You need to edit your question to show what you did, what happened, and what you expected.

Comment: Yes by using http instead of https I downloaded the source code..Thanks alot +1 for u.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a SVN link, it's Mercurial link, so you can't use svn tool. You need [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org) for this.

Comment: Last login: Mon Feb 21 19:41:58 on ttys001
kishore-babu-bs-mac-mini:~ kishorebabub$ cd desktop
kishore-babu-bs-mac-mini:desktop kishorebabub$ cd Monish_new
kishore-babu-bs-mac-mini:Monish_new kishorebabub$ hg clone https://xmppframework.googlecode.com/hg/ xmppframework
warning: xmppframework.googlecode.com certificate with fingerprint b1:af:83:76:f3:81:b0:57:70:d8:07:42:c8:c1:b3:67:38:c8:7a:bc not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes