# Get certificate fingerprint of HTTPS server from command line?

Tags: command-line, mercurial, https, certificate, google-code

Recently Mercurial has [added](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates#Changes_in_Mercurial_1.7.x) certificate validation when connecting to HTTPS servers. I'm trying to clone the wiki repository for a googlecode project at `https://wiki.pydlnadms.googlecode.com/hg/`, but the certificate is for `*.googlecode.com`. I was under the impression that this is called a wildcard domain and valid for all subdomains, but I'm receiving the error:

```
matt@stanley:~/src$ hg clone https://wiki.pydlnadms.googlecode.com/hg/ pydlnadms-wiki
abort: wiki.pydlnadms.googlecode.com certificate error: certificate is for *.googlecode.com
```

Allegedly I need to add the certificate fingerprint to my hgrc. **How do I retrieve this fingerprint from the command line?**

Parent Question: [Hosting images on Google Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137901/hosting-images-on-google-code/5162832#5162832)

Comment: There's an issue for this, as adding the certificate is just a workaround. http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=4533

Comment: If you like it, put a ring on it... See the "upvote" button.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The page at http://wiki.debuntu.org/wiki/OpenSSL#Retrieving_certificate_informations lists the command lines for that (and printing out the relevant information).  From that page and some of the man pages, it seems like what you want is (for bash):

```
openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout -in /dev/stdin
```

If you want the whole certificate, leave off the `|` symbol and everything after it.

Comment: to add a bit more detail. <host>:<port> in this example will be "wiki.pydlnadms.googlecode.com:443". http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates#Host_certificate_fingerprints has instructions on how to get this into your .hgrc file.

Comment: Hi, got the fingerprint of my server, and added [hostfingerprints] mydomain.com = 09:EA:A1:28:49:24:21... to /etc/mercurial/hgrc, but trying to clone a newely created repo gives me SSL: Server certificate verify failed [command returned code 255 Fri Sep 14 22:31:09 2012] Any clue why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The hash method can be specified as a flag (sha1, sha256, md5): ` | openssl x509 -fingerprint -sha256 -noout -in /dev/stdin`

Comment: This takes a fingerprint of all the extra garbage, like `CONNECTED(00000003)`, this doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 22):

this is also enough:

```
openssl x509 -fingerprint -in server.crt
```

Answer (score 6):

This is an old thread but there is an easier way I found. Assuming you have the crt file:

```
$ cat server.crt|openssl x509 -fingerprint 
MD5 Fingerprint=D1:BA:B0:17:66:6D:7F:42:7B:91:1E:22:7E:3A:27:D2
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Background

[Since Mercurial 3.9](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/SecureConnections), Mercurial requires the more secure SHA-256 fingerprint, as opposed to SHA-1 from prior versions.  [Jeremiah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5165073/10155767) explains how to compute the SHA-1 fingerprint.  As pointed out in J.Money's comment, one must now add the `-sha256` flag to get the correct fingerprint.

#### The new command:

```
openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -fingerprint -sha256 -noout -in /dev/stdin
```

where `<host>:<port>` should be substituted as appropriate.  (To answer the original question, one would use `wiki.pydlnadms.googlecode.com:443`, as noted by yanokwa.)  **You must omit `https://` from the URL**, otherwise you will get the error `Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`.

One can then [add the resulting SHA-256 fingerprint to Mercurial's global settings file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56579497/10155767) (`~/.hgrc`).

Answer (score 4):

Since nobody commented on this I wanted to try and clear up some of the confusion regarding subdomains:

> the certificate is for *.googlecode.com. I was under the impression
>   that this is called a wildcard domain and valid for all subdomains

You are partially correct. A wildcard certificate is valid for all *direct* subdomains but not for subdomains of subdomains.

So `*.googlecode.com` is valid for `pydlnadms.googlecode.com` but not for `wiki.pydlnadms.googlecode.com`.

For that you'd need a certificate for `*.pydlnadms.googlecode.com` or a non-wildcard certificate for `wiki.pydlnadms.googlecode.com`