# How to entirely disable SSL certificate checks in Mercurial / TortoiseHg?

Tags: ssl, mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm looking for a way to make `--insecure` option the default one for any `hg` \ TortoiseHg command.

Please don't write this is a bad practice - I aware about possible risks and consider they're fully acceptable.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Setting `cacerts` in the `[web]` section to the empty string looks to be the same thing.  From [the source](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/48d606d7192b/mercurial/dispatch.py#l560):

```
if cmdoptions.get('insecure', False):
    ui.setconfig('web', 'cacerts', '!', '--insecure')
```

which [the wiki confirms](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates#Manually_bypassing_security_checks_on_self-signed_certificates):

> Sometimes it may be expedient to
>   disable security checks, for instance
>   when dealing with hosts with
>   self-signed certificates. This can be
>   done by disabling the CA certificate
>   configuration on the command line:
>
> hg push --config web.cacerts=
>   https://self-signed-host/repo

So putting `cacerts=!` in the `[web]` section of your global hgrc (`/etc/mercurial/hgrc` on linux-likes) will get you there.

Comment: This approach really works - thanks a lot! The only issue is that Hg prints `"warning: something.com certificate with fingerprint 81:....:fe not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.c
acerts config setting)"` several times during `hg pull` and `hg push`.

Comment: So I finally decided to use an approach with `[hostfingerprints]` section.

Comment: What's more good with [hostfingerprinst] is that you can place them in repository hgrc instead of root one, so this change will not affect all the rest repositories.

Comment: @AndriyK any setting can go in the repo's `.hg/hgrc` file.  No settings are limited to specific locations in the various possible hgrc locations.

Comment: In my particular case `[web] caserts=` wasn't working on the repository level. May be I did something wrong.

Comment: You how have to web.cacerts=!

Comment: In Mercurial >= 3.9 web.cacerts=! option has been removed. https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/SecureConnections

Comment: Note to future self : (should have added this last time) - solved the problem on android + iOS by shipping the python module "certifi"

Answer (score 34):

If your goal is to eliminate certificate fingerprint warnings during push/pull, there's a better way to do this. Use the [hostfingerprints] in .hg/hgrc (or ~/.hgrc -- see comments).

```
[hostfingerprints]
server.example.org = 38:76:52:7c:87:26:9a:8f:4a:f8:d3:de:08:45:3b:ea:d6:4b:ee:cc
```

This will eliminate the warnings without eliminating the security checks.

*Note:* I see from your comments to another answer that you've already found this solution. I'm posting this anyway in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. It's exactly what I needed.

Comment: There is a nice question about getting server fingerprints using bash: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5165073/1760643

Here the command:

    `openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout -in /dev/stdin`

Comment: Mine had to go in ~/.hgrc

Answer (score 18):

You can use [aliases](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias) to achieve that. Add this to your `.hgrc` :

```
[alias]
push = push --insecure
```

Problem is you wil have to do this for each command you want to use and I suggest you use different names for your aliases than the default one.

As far as I know, there's no way to enforce `--insecure` for all commands "automatically".

Comment: This works even when Mercurial is called internally (without the parameter) - from IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: As you quietly point out, if you're going to use `alias`, you should likely use something more like `ipush = push --insecure` so it's not confused with the standard command (ie. make the user understand what's happening, don't "trick" the command to do "the wrong thing" by-default).

Answer (score 2):

#### Background

As pointed out in [Bruce Alderman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14757125/10155767), a good alternative to using the `--insecure` option is to simply add the host fingerprints to  the `~/.hgrc` file.  (It's presumably forbidden to add them to `.hg/hgrc` due to security risks.)  The `[hostfingerprints]` section however has been deprecated.

#### New instructions

Add the following to `~/.hgrc`:

```
[hostsecurity]
<host>:fingerprints=sha256:<hash>
```

where `<host>` should be substituted with the hostname (without the `https://` prefix), and `<hash>` should be substituted with the SHA-256 fingerprint (32 bytes, written as `:`-separated hexadecimal).  The output of the following [SHA-256 fingerprint command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56578902/10155767)

```
openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -fingerprint -sha256 -noout -in /dev/stdin
```

after substituting `<host>` and `<port>` is of the form

```
SHA256 Fingerprint=<hash>
```

For example, for a self-signed certificate running from the local machine, one might have an entry in `~/.hgrc` which looks like

```
[hostsecurity]
localhost:fingerprints=sha256:DD:30:5A:9B:2C:E1:59:7E:46:C4:42:D3:41:34:03:17:2A:CF:50:E8:DF:78:E6:2E:C9:42:D9:9A:C9:58:AC:52
```

There is further documentation on [Mercurial's page about secure connections.](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/SecureConnections)