# Pulling from Mercurial - certificate error

Tags: mercurial, certificate, hgrc

I was trying to pull from a server, and I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\User\hg_repo>hg pull
abort: error: _ssl.c:490: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICAT
E:certificate verify failed
```

I have downloaded the certificate and installed it into Windows' Trusted Root Certification Authorities, but I still get the error. How can I get Mercurial to trust the certificate?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your user directory (e.g. C:\Users\ on Vista/Windows 7 or C:\Documents and Settings\ before that), there should be a file called 'mercurial.ini' (or if there isn't, just create an empty file with that name). Append a section to the bottom of that file that looks like this:

```
[web]
cacerts = C:\the\path\to\the\certificate\file.cer
```

Comment: You don't need a dummy file, `cacerts =` with no path will work fine.

Comment: Thank very much, Keyo! cacerts = with no path worked.

Comment: @Keyo That [disables security checks](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates#Manually_bypassing_security_checks_on_self-signed_certificates) entirely

Comment: I found that I had to put `cacerts =!` as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5371180/896559