# HiveMQ-Cloud get ssl fingerprint / cert for MQTT

Tags: ssl, mqtt, hivemq

I'm trying to use the hivemq-Cloud service (https://console.hivemq.cloud/). Unfortunately I'm forced to use the ssl option and I can't figure out how I can download the public key / fingerprint.

Somebody familiar with the service?

I created a cluster and got something like this
somehash.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud:8883 then I created a user and testet the connection with this service: http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/. It only works with the option 'ssl' enabled.

I thought I can catch the fingerprint via ssh-keyscan:

```
ssh-keyscan -p 8883 <somehash>.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud
<somehash>.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud: Connection closed by remote host
<somehash>.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud: Connection closed by remote host
<somehash>.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud: Connection closed by remote host
```

And I got this message. How can I get the public key from a himemq-mqtt service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't worked for me with keyscan but with openssl.
Here is the solution for my problem:
[Get certificate fingerprint of HTTPS server from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164804/get-certificate-fingerprint-of-https-server-from-command-line)

```
openssl s_client -connect <somehash>.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud:8883 < /dev/null 2>/dev
/null | openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout -in /dev/stdin
```